# PHP rawurlencode function encodes differently than the browser

Tags: php, encoding

When I enter the string `DIN 2080 Fräseraufnahmen SK 30` into the browser, it encodes it as `DIN%202080%20Fr%C3%A4seraufnahmen%20SK%2030`, and the API properly reads this.  However, in a PHP script to call the same API, when I encode the string using the function `rawurlencode()`, it is encoded as `DIN%202080%20Fra%CC%88seraufnahmen%20SK%2030`.  This causes the same API to misidentify the string as not matching.  How do I encode the string in PHP so that it will be same same as encoded by the browser?

Browser:

`DIN%202080%20Fr%C3%A4seraufnahmen%20SK%2030`

PHP `rawurlencode()`:

`DIN%202080%20Fra%CC%88seraufnahmen%20SK%2030`

**Addendum:**
After further checking, I found that the problem is caused by php composer's autoloader.  However, Sitethief's answer fixes this.

test program:

```
<?php
require_once(__DIR__ . '/vendor/autoload.php');
echo '<pre>' . rawurlencode($_GET['a']) . '</pre>';
echo '<br />';
echo '<pre>' . rawurlencode(Normalizer::normalize($_GET['a'], Normalizer::FORM_C)) . '</pre>';
```

script called as `/test.php?a=ä`
Output:

`a%CC%88`

`%C3%A4`

Comment: I found that this question is incorrect and not caused by `rawurlencode()` but rather by other code that is messing up the $_GET.  Since there are answers, I can't delte it, so I'm closing the question.

Comment: Please see Sitethief's answer as the difference is between an `a` with a combining mark, and the single-codepoint version of `ä`. This could be due to differing normalization forms as suggested, or a general lack of normalization.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the PHP [Normalizer](https://www.php.net/manual/en/class.normalizer.php) class to convert the string using the same normalization form as the browser uses. You do need to have the `intl` PHP extension installed for this to work though.

This should be how this would work:

```
$normalizedString = Normalizer::normalize($inputString, Normalizer::FORM_C);
```

Answer (score -2):

Based on my experience, it seems like the character set of the editor (vscode…) is the problem.

Check whether the editor character set is UTF-8.

[image]

Comment: How does this answer the question?  Not using an editor to get these converted strings.
With my PHP script, I get the input already decoded, and I need to encode it to properly send it to the API.
With my call to the API directly, the browser encodes the input to make it only contain standard characters, encoding the special characters.  When I copy the url from the browser, I get the encoding.

Comment: Also, both representations are perfectly valid UTF-8.